# When running a task with a batch job as stream there is no entry in the jobs section of the dashobard

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a task that contains a batch job as stream.

When I run this batch job as task I see entries under Jobs in the dashboard.
But when I run the task from a stream with a stream launcher I cannot see a job execution.

Is there a way that these executions also appear in the Jobs section?

Additionally does anybody now where can I see stream executions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comment from Sabby Anandan:

Unless and until the datasource is the same between SCDF and the Task, you wouldn't see them in the Dashboard. Basically, at runtime, the Tasks/Jobs themselves attempt to record their execution on the schema shared with SCDF and the SCDF Dashboard, simply queries for all the information from that schema, so sharing the same datasource is the key.

Refer to the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sharing-spring-cloud-dataflows-datastore-with-tasks

Answer (score 1):

Only batch jobs have the Spring Batch model and the backing relational database model (for job executions/step executions/history etc.,). Hence, the tasks that are batch jobs have the associated job executions entry in the BATCH JOB tables.

But for all the tasks, the task executions are stored in the configured data base `TASK_EXECUTION` (the default prefix is `TASK_`).

For more information on configuration of database for Spring Cloud Data Flow and Spring Cloud Task, you can see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sharing-spring-cloud-dataflows-datastore-with-tasks)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware of that. But my question is if a stream executes a task and this task executes a batch job why don't I see it under Jobs.

Comment: Unless and until the `datasource` is the same between SCDF and the Task, you wouldn't see them in the Dashboard. Basically, at runtime, the Tasks/Jobs themselves attempt to record their execution on the schema shared with SCDF and the SCDF Dashboard, simply queries for all the information from that schema, so sharing the same `datasource` is the key. Refer to the docs linked in the answer ^^.